# How to use PhysX™ Candy Wrapper in XNA

Tags: xna, physx

I need some basic tutorial or guide on how to use "PhysX™ Candy Wrapper".

On their website I couldn't find anything useful what so ever.

It has been a long time since I touched 3D programming and I would like to start learning the new stuff that is currently going on.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PhysX Candy Wrapper attempts to preserve the original API as much as possible, you should be able to follow the tutorials that NVIDIA provides with the SDK. Even if you don't use C++, they should be quite simple to understand.

To get you started, add a reference to the eyecm.PhysX assembly and take a look a the Physics class. Its static Create methods will give you an interface to all of the PhysX functionality.

I've also set up a forum at [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/eyecm-physx/index.php) where you can ask specific questions.